# When I import Alerts component into App.js, I get following error

Tags: reactjs, redux

react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

// App.js

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider as AlertProvider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic'
import Header from './layout/Header'
import Dashboard from "./leads/Dashboard";
import Alerts from "./Alerts";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from "../store";

const alertOptions = {
    timeout: 3000,
    position: 'top center'
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
                    <Fragment>
                        <Header />
                        <Alerts />
                        <div className="container">
                            <Dashboard />
                        </div>
                    </Fragment>
                </AlertProvider>
            </Provider>
        ) 
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

// Alerts.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { withAlert } from 'react-alert'

export class Alerts extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.alert.show('It Worked')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment />
        )
    }
}


export default withAlert(Alerts)
```

Comment: Can you please add code snippet of your AlertProvider Component. I guess the issue might be due to that you are  trying to render the entire object in JSX.  Try accessing the individual property of the object in JSX. In the Alerts component you are accessing the props but you had not passed any props to Alerts component in App component.

Comment: AlertProvider is an alias of Provider from react-alert library, and tried to pass the prop in Alerts but still the error persists, as I remove <Alerts /> below the <Header /> from code, the app runs again successfully, so some problem in Alerts itself